# How to access window object from XUL?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to set an `onLoad` event to the current web page from a firefox extension. I'm using the `gBrowser` object but I'm not sure if this is the best way. I would like to set an `onLoad` event to the web page window to execute some actions of the plugin as soon as the page is loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts I found a solution for this. Lets say we have a `function` called `pageLoaded`, which is the one we want to call when the website has been totally loaded. Now, we have to add an event listener to the `gBrowser` object to catch the `load` event.

Here the code:

```
function pageLoaded(){
    alert("the page has been loaded")
}

gBrowser.addEventListener("load", pageLoaded, true);
```

I recommend to use add an event listener to the extension document before to add it to the gBrowser. The result would be something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    gBrowser.addEventListener("load", pageLoaded, true);
}, false);
```

I hope this solution will be useful for someone.

Thanks for reading.